# How to define spring profiles for different stages with many ANDs, ORs and NOTs?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-properties

I have three stages - `stage-dev, stage-qa, stage-live`,
three datacenters - `dc1, dc2, dc3` and three brands - `brand1, brand2, brand3`.

I created three different property files - `application-stage-dev.yml, application-stage-qa.yml` and `application-stage-live.yml` and put related properties in it.

For example:

```
#common live properties here
spring:
   profiles: stage-live 

#brand1 specific live properties here
spring:
   profiles: stage-live, brand1
```

If I want to define some specific profile definitions (e.g `stage-live & dc1 & !brand` or `(stage-dev | stage-qa) & brand1`) the application does not load the right property. But if I do the same definitions in the `application.yml` file where I put all properties together, it works fine.

How can I separate the properties into different yaml files (based on stages) and define mixed profile definitions?